# Where is the Azure web root for a container?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, containers

I've deployed a web application (ReactJS/NodeJS) via container in Azure. The container image has been pushed to the Azure Registry and everything deploys just fine. The web application works as expected.

However, if I ssh into the server or use the Kudu service by using `https://[SITE-NAME].scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/` (Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu)), I see only a single file in `wwwroot` called `hostingstart.html`

[image]

My question is: where is the actual web root of my container? It's certainly not in `wwwroot`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about containers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck finding the answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never did. Godspeed to you.